# Evaluate $\int_{C} (z-z^2)dz$ where $C$ is the (i)Upper half of the circle $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate $\int_{C} (z-z^2)dz$ where $C$ is the
>
> (i)Upper half of the circle $|z|=1$
>
> (ii)Lower half of the circle.
>
> Where $z$ is a complex number.

How can I approach this problem?

What I know:

$z=x+iy$

$\int_{C} (x+iy-(x+iy)^2)d(x+iy)$

$\int_{C} (x+iy-(x^2-y^2+2xyi))d(x+iy)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{z^2}2-\dfrac{z^3}3$ is a primitive of the function that you want to integrate.

Comment: Sir, I don't know what a primitive is but I see that if we integrate $z-z^2$ with respect to $z$, then we get $\dfrac{z^2}2-\dfrac{z^3}3$, if $z$ is a real number.

Comment: Since $\left(\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}3\right)'=z-z^2$, if you compute $\int_\gamma z-z^2\,\mathrm dz$, where $\gamma$ is a path from $z_0$ to $z_1$, then$$\int_\gamma z-z^2\,\mathrm dz=\left(\frac{{z_1}^2}2-\frac{{z_1}^3}3\right)-\left(\frac{{z_0}^2}2-\frac{{z_0}^3}3\right).$$

Comment: Ok, Thanks sir. I am solving the problem and reporting back.

Comment: Sir, is the answer $\frac{-2}{3}$ in both the cases?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is!

Comment: Thanks sir. Have a great day....